# how to deal with a ISR on atmega324pb?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt

I have this problem:
I want to make a difference between the triggers (BTN0 and BTN1 - pins for this 2 buttons are in the same Interrupt vector - PCINT2). How could I know who triggers the ISR?

this is the code for BTN0 (what I need to add to use both buttons?):

```
#pragma vector=PCINT2_vect
  __interrupt void btn01_press(void)
  {
        
    unsigned char current_btn0_state = BTN0; 
    unsigned char prev_btn0_state = !current_btn0_state;
    
    unsigned char current_btn1_state = BTN=1; 
    unsigned char prev_btn1state = !current_btn1_state;
   
     
    if(current_btn0_state == BTN_RELEASED && prev_btn0_state == BTN_PRESSED) 
      {
      
        if(LED0 == LED_OFF)
          {
            if(current_btn0_state && BTN0 == BTN_RELEASED) // for debouncing
              {
                led_PowerOn_number(L0);
                current_btn0_state = !current_btn0_state;
              }
          }
        else
          {
            if(BTN0 == BTN_RELEASED)
              {
                led_PowerOff_number(L0);
                current_btn0_state = !current_btn0_state;
              }
          }
        return;
    }


// this is is also true, and is executed with first (for BTN0), but i want to be triggered separately.   
// 
//    if(current_btn1_state == BTN_RELEASED && prev_btn1_state == BTN_PRESSED)
//    {
//    
//        if(LED1 == LED_OFF)
//          {
//            if(current_btn1_state && BTN1 == BTN_RELEASED)
//              {
//                led_PowerOn_number(1);
//                initial_btn1_state = !initial_btn1_state;
//              }
//          }
//        else
//          {
//            if(BTN1 == BTN_RELEASED)
//              {
//                led_PowerOff_number(1);
//                initial_btn1_state = !initial_btn1_state;
//              }
//          }
//        return;
//      } 

}
```

some answers. a solution. thnks

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to use interrupts for buttons - it is possible but a lot more complex than what you have here - the way of debouncing in the ISR isn't reliable since you will catch a lot of spurious interrupts during bouncing.

The professional solution is to instead use a cyclic timer interrupt with an interval of 5ms or 10ms. Let the ISR concern itself with debouncing alone. Leave the decision regarding which button that was pressed etc to the surrounding button driver.

It might look like (pseudo code):

```
static volatile uint8_t buttons;

static void timer_isr (void)  // called every 5/10ms etc
{
  static uint8_t prev_port;
  uint8_t port = PORT; // read the register

  if(port == prev_port)
  {
    buttons = port; // only use values that have been stable for 5ms/10ms etc
  } 
  prev_port = port;

  /* clear flags, reset timer etc as required by the timer peripheral */
}

bool is_button_x_pressed (void) // public function called by the user
{
  return buttons & BUTTON_X_MASK;
}
```

Comment: thank you. i am a beginner in embedded and you helped me with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. partialy. the problem was in my logic of pressed/released button ( pressed == 0 ). now i need a solution for debouncing without soft delay.

```
 #pragma vector=PCINT2_vect
  __interrupt void btn01_press(void)
  {
    unsigned char current_btn0_state = BTN0;
    unsigned char current_btn1_state = BTN1; 

    if(current_btn0_state == BTN_PRESSED) // ISR for BTN0
      {
        if(LED0 == LED_OFF)
          {
              led_Sdelay(DEBOUNCING_TIME);
              led_PowerOn_number(L0);
              current_btn0_state = !current_btn0_state;
          }
        else
          {
              led_Sdelay(DEBOUNCING_TIME);
              led_PowerOff_number(L0);
              current_btn0_state = !current_btn0_state;
          }
            return;
      }
       
     if(current_btn1_state == BTN_PRESSED) // ISR for BTN0
      {
        if(LED1 == LED_OFF)
          {
              led_Sdelay(DEBOUNCING_TIME);
              led_PowerOn_number(L1);
              current_btn1_state = !current_btn1_state;
          }
        else
          {
              led_Sdelay(DEBOUNCING_TIME);    
              led_PowerOff_number(L1);
              current_btn1_state = !current_btn1_state;
          }
          return;
    }
        
 }
```

Comment: Adding delays inside an ISR is a cardinal sin. Forget about this idea entirely - I posted an answer.

Comment: Here's a nice [timer-based debounce idea](https://hackaday.com/2015/12/10/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-ii/) that I've used in the past.